# PostgreSQL order by two columns with nullable last

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have the table:

| id | date | bonus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-10 16:11:06.445559 | 6000 |
| 2 | 2022-03-15 16:11:06.445559 | 4000 |
| 3 | 2022-03-20 16:11:06.445559 | null |
| 4 | 2022-03-25 16:11:06.445559 | 7000 |
| 5 | 2022-03-30 16:11:06.445559 | null |

I need to order rows by date and bonus columns, using PostgreSQL syntax. First should be newest (order by date) rows with non-nullable bonuses. Then should be rows with nullable bonus ordered by date (also newest first)
Result should be next:

| id | date | bonus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2022-03-25 16:11:06.445559 | 7000 |
| 2 | 2022-03-15 16:11:06.445559 | 4000 |
| 1 | 2022-03-10 16:11:06.445559 | 6000 |
| 5 | 2022-03-30 16:11:06.445559 | null |
| 3 | 2022-03-20 16:11:06.445559 | null |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional for **`bonus`** while it has higher precedence, and then descendingly sorted **`date`** as the lower precedence such as

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN bonus IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, date DESC
```

**<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0d04b92df41b89452d90b3d05bbf9c59)</kbd>**

Comment: There is no need for the CASE, just just a NULLS LAST: ORDER BY bonus DESC NULLS LAST, date DESC;

Comment: @FrankHeikens  That wouldn't treat all IS NOT NULL bonus as tied, which is what he seems to want.

Comment: @FrankHeikens that would not give the result OP wanted. All non-null bonuses first, ordered by time (not ordered by bonus), after that null bonuses ordered by time.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
ORDER BY
    bonus IS NULL ASC,
    date DESC;
```

`bonus IS NULL` is a boolean and you can sort by it. In my opinion it's a bit cleaner (at least shorter) than `CASE`